# TabIndex control in a non compliant html page

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, internet-explorer, label

I have an html page where I cannot put a DOCTYPE (I am not allowed to). Plus, I need to make it work on IE 8!
Then there is a checkbox + label thing.
For example, this:

```
    <input id="daffodils" type="checkbox" title="daffodil factsheet" name="daffodils" value="checkbox" tabindex=2>
    <label for="daffodils">Daffodils</label>
    <input id="tulips" type="checkbox" title="tulip factsheet" name="tulips" value="checkbox" tabindex=3>
    <label for="tulips">Tulips</label>
```

My problem: 
I want to get the checkbox highlighted when I Tab around, but with this code, only the Labels get highlighted. I tried using TabIndex. but it didn't help.
Of course, the checkbox can be checked/unchecked, but I wanted the checkbox to be highlighted. (By highlighted - I mean ..the dotted square around an object)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not pretty, but it might work for you:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Whatever</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function focusThis(This) {
        This.className='focus';
      }

      function blurThis(This) {
        This.className='blur';
      }
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
      .focus {
        border: 1px dotted black;
      }

      .blur {
        border: 1px solid white;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="daffodils" onfocus="focusThis(this);" onblur="blurThis(this);" type="checkbox" title="daffodil factsheet" name="daffodils" value="checkbox" tabindex=2>
    <label for="daffodils">Daffodils</label>
    <input id="tulips" onfocus="focusThis(this);" onblur="blurThis(this);" type="checkbox" title="tulip factsheet" name="tulips" value="checkbox" tabindex=3>
    <label for="tulips">Tulips</label>
  </body>
</html>
```

Notice the `onfocus` and `onblur` events on the input boxes.

**Edit:**

If you're open to using the jQuery library, you can easily get away from the `onfocus` and `onblur` events inside the input tags by just adding and removing the `focus` class:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Whatever</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input').focus(function(){
          $(this).addClass('focus');
        }).blur(function(){
          $(this).removeClass('focus');
        });
      });
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
      .focus {
        border: 1px dotted black;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="daffodils" type="checkbox" title="daffodil factsheet" name="daffodils" value="checkbox" tabindex=2>
    <label for="daffodils">Daffodils</label>
    <input id="tulips" type="checkbox" title="tulip factsheet" name="tulips" value="checkbox" tabindex=3>
    <label for="tulips">Tulips</label>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm sure someone could write the JS code to do the same, but I prefer jQuery.

Comment: Nice hack. Perhaps I'll have to go for it.
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I added a jQuery example to show how to make it easier if you're willing to use this library.

Comment: I added a different hack (which doesn't work in Firefox) but solves my purpose. I made Label1 the label for Checkbox and Label2 label for Lable1.

Answer (score 0):

Is it allowed not to use `<label>`?

```
<div style="cursor:default;" onclick="this.childNodes[0].focus();this.childNodes[0].click();"><input id="daffodils" type="checkbox" title="daffodil factsheet" name="daffodils" value="checkbox" tabindex=2><span>Daffodils</span></div>
<div style="cursor:default;" onclick="this.childNodes[0].focus();this.childNodes[0].click();"><input id="tulips" type="checkbox" title="tulip factsheet" name="tulips" value="checkbox" tabindex=3><span for="tulips">Tulips</span></div>
```

That will be fine.

for every checkbox, suurround them in 
`<div style="cursor:default;" onclick="this.childNodes[0].focus();this.childNodes[0].click();"><input /><span /></div>`
And that's all done.

Comment: This in an interesting suggestion. But the problem is : Now if I click (using mouse) the Text (Daffodils), the checkbox will not be checked/unchecked. I think for attribute is only for Labels.

Comment: It sure is a hack and it makes the form less accessible than using labels.